# How to enter in window vista home? Product key error

Tags: windows-vista, operating-systems, product-key

I have problem with my OS (Windows Vista Premium 32 bit). If I enter Vista, its asking for a product key but I don't know my product key.

Please note, I have dual OS in my desktop.

Comment: Why don't you know your product key? Did the OS come with your computer?

Comment: Do you know if your copy of Vista is legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS already was installed when purchased then there should be a sticker on the box (on the computer).

If you've got your own DVD then it will have come in the DVD case.

If you need to get a serial back and don't have physial access then you can try to retrieve it direct from the computer it was installed on using [magical jelly bean key finder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)

*The Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder is a freeware utility that retrieves your Product Key (cd key) used to install windows from your registry. It also has a community-updated configuration file that retrieves product keys for many other applications. Another feature is the ability to retrieve product keys from unbootable Windows installations.*

Comment: I have missed my dvd then how to get my product key...any other solution...

Comment: and if you've downloaded it illegally be very careful there aren't any nasties built in (aside from it being illegal! - naughty). A favourite of malware writers is to provide knocked of OS's with pre existing vunerabilities.

Comment: @JoeTaylor  - if you've downloaded anything illegal tough luck with what you get! :)

Comment: @DaveRook Indeed, I always find its a good way to put people off though. "Sure you get this for free, but maybe the baddies get your bank account details" - usually deters wannabe Jack Sparrows